# How to determine why my Android app stopped running?

Tags: android, debugging

I wrote a simple Android app that functions as a digital sign -- all it does is download and display a (simple, static) web page, and it automatically refreshes the web page once every four hours, with no user interaction.

It generally runs fine for days or weeks at a time, but every so often (seemingly at random intervals) when I go down to where one of the units is deployed I find that the app has mysteriously stopped running -- i.e. the device has returned to the Android desktop.

I instrumented my app to emit log messages (both by calling Log.i and by writing text to a separate log file) and I don't see any evidence that the app crashed or that it exited intentionally; it just seems that at one point it went to sleep after refreshing the web page (as usual), and was never heard from again.  I also did a "adb shell logcat" to examine the device's system log after the fault occurred, and I didn't see any stack traces; but I'm not sure how far back that log goes.

Does anyone have any idea why an app might mysteriously go away?  Alternatively, is there a recommended way to debug this problem?  Since it only happens once every few weeks, it's difficult to reproduce the fault.  In particular, is there a better way than "adb shell logcat" to view any crashes that may have occurred in the last few days or weeks?

Comment: Killed by android OS prehaps? Stuff like task manager or even the android OS is known to kill off the app. Unless your app is a service, running with a Sticky Intent, most probably like what I suspect,your app got killed

Comment: Hi C_Rance, can you think of a reason why the app would be killed, if it is the only thing running on the device, and the device wasn't touched by the user?

Comment: judging that there might be some android services running in backend, there might be more than 1 app running. I can't really give you a good explanation on why it works like this, but holding on a android device, i do noticed that for instance I open the browser and go to the net. I can go to home screen and switch back to the browser. if I leave my phone for few hours, that state is lost. not sure if this helps you. But if your app is on the foreground, then I am not sure why this happens